# Arithmetic Left shift time complexity

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

What is the **time complexity** of * Arithmetic left shift* / * Arithmetic right shift* operators of a n bit operand  for example doing  x = y << 2; whow much time will it take ?

Comment: Less than a nano second?

Comment: you can shift it more than 32 times. You just get an overflow

Comment: The circuit depth of a barrel shifter of width `n` is O(log n), but that only matters if you're making hardware otherwise your `n` is just a constant.

Comment: @JohnSmith Not with a single expression on ints, you can't. [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19): `If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance.` And six bits for longs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexity, with the O(…) notation, is an asymptotic characterization of the time an algorithm takes when the input size becomes larger and larger. It is meaningless for algorithms that can take only a finite number of inputs. `<<` can take 2^32 * 32 different inputs, hence a finite number of inputs, therefore it is constant-time (O(1)).

Comment: This doesn't solve the question. In theory, how much asymptotic time does it take?

Comment: You can say anything in the computer takes $O(1)$ time with a similar argument... This doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @nirshahar what part of “[asymptotic complexity] is meaningless for algorithms that can take only a finite number of inputs” is confusing you?

Comment: It is not confusing me. What confuses me is why assume that `<<` is an operation that can take only a finite number of inputs. Can't we compute `<<` for arbitrary numbers? Of course we can...

Comment: Maybe standardized computers can't do that in one single operation, but it is possible. So I suggest splitting the answer for the practical case and for the theoretical case (asymptotic notation for a general input)