# turning off leftmost non zero bit of a number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

how can I turn off leftmost `non-zero` bit of a number in `O(1)`?

for example

```
n = 366 (base 10) = 101101110 (in base 2)
```

then after turning the leftmost `non-zero` bit off ,number looks like = `001101110`

n will always be >0

Comment: @SurayansTiwari, are you sure that an `O(1)` algorithm exists?

Comment: I am not sure that's why I asked it here

Comment: "after turning the leftmost non-zero bit off" so basically if the number is 00101101 you want the output to be 00001101, right?

Comment: Theoretically there should be a O( log(n) ) algorithm by using binary search to find the highest set bit. But I doubt that this will improve performance unless n is very high.

Comment: yes you are right niceman

Comment: dividing the number by 2 repeatedly is an O(lgN) algo

Comment: I suggest to change your example so the OPS will understand, I only noticed now

Comment: oh sorry missed that

Comment: i tried an O(logn) algo by repeatedly dividing the number by 2 and storing remainder in a string until the quotient is not zero, later changing the first character to 0 and then converting again to decimal gives the number –

Comment: if the number is read from a stream like cin or any other, then you should consider the reading process and I don't think it's O(1) algo

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you insist on `O(1)` under any circumstances, the Intel Intrinsics function `_bit_scan_reverse()` defined in `immintrin.h` does a hardware find for the most-significant non-zero bit in a int number.

Though the operation does use a loop (functional equivalent), I believe its constant time given its latency at fixed 3 (as per [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)).

The function will return the index to the most-significant non-zero bit thus doing a simple:

```
n = n & ~(1 << _bit_scan_reverse(n));
```

should do.

This intrinsic is undefined for n == 0. So you gotta watch out there. I'm following the assumption of your original post where n > 0.

Comment: see the comments, the bit which will be turned off is not always MSB, like this one 00111011 will turns into 00011011

Comment: @niceman Oops, forgot to mention. The function finds the most significant non-zero bit (as opposed to just the MSB). Will edit answer.

Comment: @SurayansTiwari Are you targeting a x86/x86_64 architecture and did you import "immintrin.h"? You need SSE enabled in your compiler to use it.

Comment: Nice, GCC compiles this to `bsr` / `btr`.  https://godbolt.org/z/8fjeoxsPE

Answer (score 3):

`n = 2^x + y.
x = log(n) base 2`

Your highest set bit is `x`.

So in order to reset that bit, 
`number &= ~(1 << x);`

Another approach:

```
int highestOneBit(int i) {
    i |= (i >>  1);
    i |= (i >>  2);
    i |= (i >>  4);
    i |= (i >>  8);
    i |= (i >> 16);
    return i - (i >> 1);
}

int main() {
    int n = 32767;
    int z = highestOneBit(n); // returns the highest set bit number i.e 2^x.
    cout<< (n&(~z)); // Resets the highest set bit.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well since log(n) is actually doing a loop, this isn't O(1) algo, except if you can make log(n) O(1)

Comment: Missed that. Correct. Lets explore more :)

Comment: please note from my comment on the question that 0010011 will output to 0000011

Comment: Yes. The output should be 3 and it is. Am I missing something?

Comment: Unless I missed something: your highestOneBit(19) (19 = 0010011) returns 16.

Comment: Yes. and the answer would be (n&(~16)) which I have printed.

Comment: But it's still O(logn) right? Just with an unrolled loop.

Comment: Not sure. Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470210/arithmetic-left-shift-time-complexity

Comment: `i` should be unsigned, otherwise an arithmetic right shift will shift in 1s for numbers with the high bit set: https://godbolt.org/z/a83qxd6G6

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i), for a possibly faster solution, using a processor instruction.

However, an O(lgN) solution is:

```
int cmsb(int x)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (x >>= 1) {
        ++count;
    }

    return x & ~(1 << count);
}
```

Comment: good answer, O(lgN) is better than O(N) but it's still not an answer since he wants it to be O(1)

Comment: This is O(num_bits), the number of bits in a register, which is the N in most bit-manipulation operations where we're not considering the bit-pattern as representing a number.  And since you used signed `int`, it will infinite-loop if the MSB is set (i.e. if x is negative)

Answer (score -1):

If ANDN is not supported and LZCNT is supported, the fastest O(1) way to do it is not something along the lines of `n = n & ~(1 << _bit_scan_reverse(n));` but rather...

```
int reset_highest_set_bit(int x)
{
    const int mask = 0x7FFFFFFF; // 011111111[...]

    return x & (mask >> __builtin_clz(x));
}
```

Comment: This is broken, e.g. `x = 0x7fffffff` makes it return `1`.  Perhaps you wanted `mask >> __builtin_clz(x)` to shift by the leading-zero count?  BSR gives you 31-clz, i.e. the position of the highest set bit.  Also, these should be unsigned, especially `1U << 31` to avoid signed overflow in your constant expression.  https://godbolt.org/z/q66Evj74K.  https://godbolt.org/z/8fjeoxsPE has a working version.

Comment: Thanks - I though "BSF = TZCNT <=> BSR = LZCNT" (except for zero input) but the latter ones are actually totally different instructions.

I don't see where `(int)1 << 31` does not result in `0x80000000` and more importantly where `((int)1 << 31) - 1` does not produce `0x7FFFFFFF`.

Comment: 32-bit `int` (like x86 C implementations use) can't represent `+0x80000000` - that 32-bit bit-pattern represents a negative number as signed 2's complement.  Thus, that left-shift of `1` (of type signed `int`) has signed overflow to INT_MIN, which is undefined behaviour in C.  And then the `-1` also has undefined behaviour, wrapping back to INT_MAX.  It does happens to work in this case on mainstream compilers, but there's no reason to rely on undefined behaviour when you could just write `1U` to work with unsigned numbers.  That's almost always what you want for bit-manipulation.

Comment: It would be a lot better to simply use `INT_MAX` or `UINT_MAX>>1` - that would be portable to all `int` or `unsigned` widths supported by GNU C.  (This code is now portable, now that you've replaced an x86 intrinsic with a GNU C builtin.)

Comment: I guess it makes sense :) Although I tested it to make sure.
In my version i actually write 0x7FFFFFFF but I wanted to make a little more readable or rather inferable, although that's definitely debatable ("why "-1"?"). 
Thanks again, though!

Comment: `INT_MAX` has the advantage of working for any width of `int`, including stuff like AVR or MSP430 microcontrollers where  GCC uses 16-bit `int`.  But sure, writing out the bit-pattern does illustrate how it works more directly.