# Counter Game program in Hacker Rank

Tags: c#

I have solved the problem of HackerRank with c#. But while submitting the code Test cases from 9 gets terminated due to timeout error.

Louise and Richard have developed a numbers game. They pick a number and check to see if it is a power of 2. If it is, they divide it by 2. If not, they reduce it by the next lower number which is a power of 2. Whoever reduces the number to 1 wins the game. Louise always starts.

Given an initial value, determine who wins the game.

Example

It's Louise's turn first. She determines that 132 is not a power of 2. The next lower power of 2 is 128, so she subtracts that from 132 and passes 4 to Richard. 4 is a power of 2, so Richard divides it by 2 and passes 2 to Louise. Likewise, 2 is a power so she divides it by 2 and reaches 1. She wins the game.

Update If they initially set counter to 1, Richard wins. Louise cannot make a move so she loses.

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'counterGame' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return a STRING.
     * The function accepts LONG_INTEGER n as parameter.
     */

    public static string counterGame(long n)
    {
        // Write your code here
        int isWho = 0;
        
        while(n != 1)
        {
            int pow=0;
            long n_maximus = n;
            
            while(n_maximus > 1)
            {
                n_maximus >>= 1; 
                pow++; 
            }

            long minPow = 1 << pow; 
            if(n - minPow == 0)
            {
                n = n >> 1; 
            }
            else 
            {
                n -= minPow; 
            }
            
            isWho++; /
            
        }
        
        return (isWho & 1) != 0 ? "Louise" : "Richard";
    }

}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        int t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

        for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++)
        {
            long n = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

            string result = Result.counterGame(n);

            textWriter.WriteLine(result);
        }

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code is working but slow, it's probably better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please ensure that it is working and slow, and not simply buggy though, as Code Review does require that code is working.

Comment: Hint, try using `long.MaxValue / 2` and see how long it takes to compute, then look at what is consuming all that time and try to come up with a better approach.

Comment: You could use bitwise "tricks" to optimize your solution. Number `x` is a power of two if `x & (x - 1) == 0`. Subtracting by the next lower number which is a power of 2 is nothing more then setting the leftmost bit to 0, which you could do [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742068/4778343).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for timeout is `long minPow = 1 << pow;`. If you debug your code with some large value, you'll see that `minPow` is not even close the value you would expect.

For example, try your code with 660570904136157. `pow` will be 49, and `1 << pow` will be 131072, but you would expect 562949953421312.

The reason for that is because 1 is an `int`, and not `long`. What you actually get is `1 << 17`, i.e. `1 << (49 - 32)`. To get correct result you should specify that 1 is a `long` with `1L`. Your code will pass all tests when you change `long minPow = 1 << pow;` with `long minPow = 1L << pow;`.